# How to enable auto indentation in lists and list items?

Tags: css

I am new to CSS, I took over someone's CSS code which has:

```
.. CSS Reset .. ul, ol, li .. {
   ..
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   ..
}
```

However, setting padding to 0 effectively disables automatic list item indentation, but I want indentation, so I wrote:

```
<ul style="padding: 10;">
    <li style="padding: 10;">
        <ul style="padding: 10;">
            <li  style="padding: 10;">123</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

`padding: 10` does not have any effect, browser still displays no padding, thus no indentation.

How do I get auto indentation back in place?

Comment: @JoshC the entire UI is broken if I remove it.

Comment: Can you provide an jsFiddle.. I will be able to help if you demonstrate the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Friend, it is 10px not 10 for the padding value.

```
 <li  style="padding: 10;">123</li>
```

should be

```
 <li  style="padding: 10px;">123</li>
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

You get padding from the user **agent stylesheet** or also known as the browser stylesheet. Your **user** stylesheet overrides this. You need to remove the ol, ul, li selectors from your css style rule which tells these elements that they don't have padding or margins applied. Also that's the first time I have seen `padding: auto` is that really possible?

Comment: He just wants the default margin and padding back, right? If so he just has to remove the elements from the reset.

Comment: can I specify a class for CSS to exclude?

Comment: this answers the question. I'm betting though the original reason was to remove padding/ margin from certain usages of ul/li/ol's well you can remove the rules to get rid of the override but I'm guessing you'll need them somewhere, so you can either create a new class that has  0 margin padding and add it to existing items or create a new class that gets added to all new items and has a specific rule for margin and padding

Comment: Auto isn't a valid value for padding, for sho

Comment: @CSgoose I put a number instead of auto in padding, still there is no indentation.

Comment: @Howard Guo, your best bet is to leave the reset alone and add classes to the list items you want the padding or margin applied.

Comment: @Howard Guo Add px to the end of the number. You can't just have the number alone.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yR4uB/3/ might help. I did one with padding inline and one with classes, you want to make sure that the class you write is underneath the original rule or it will get overriden

Answer (score 0):

If you have to work with someone else’s CSS that uses CSS Reset, then you simply have to style *everything* on your own. So if you want a list to have some indents, you need to create them yourself, and you probably need to use a `class` or `id` attribute on the list elements that you want to have affected.

In general, yhere is no way to get the browser’s *default* styling back when you have overridden it with CSS Reset. You can only explicitly override the override. Assuming you have `<ul class=foo>` so that you want that list and all `ul` lists inside it to have indentation, you can set

```
ul#foo, ul#foo ul { padding-left: 40px }
```

This establishes the “expected” default indentation as per HTML5 CR. This corresponds reasonably well to typical browser defaults, but actual defaults may still differ.

If you do not wish to establish something that is expected to match defaults but some reasonable indentation, you can use the `em` unit, which adapts to font size, and use a relatively small value:

```
ul#foo, ul#foo ul { padding-left: 1.3em }
```